# Are these Messages between Pontius Pilate and Herod real?

Tags: history, reference-request, herod, pontius-pilate

Are the messages between Pontius Pilate and Herod real or are there no real epistles found between Herod and Pilate?

[The source](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arabchurch.com%2Fforums%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D152778), here is the exact part that I am talking about:

> From Pilate to Herod, the head of the quarter, Peace: I know and
>   confirm, that on the day Jesus converted to me, I flattered myself and
>   confirmed by washing my hands that I was innocent From the blood of
>   those who rose from the grave after three days, You have been pleased,
>   because you wanted me to share with you in the crucifixion, But I knew
>   of the executioners and the soldiers who guarded his grave He rose
>   from death and I was sure what I was told: He physically appeared in
>   Galilee, in the same form, In the same voice, in the same teachings,
>   and with the same disciples, Nothing has changed in anything, just
>   preaching his resurrection And with an eternal kingdom, and behold,
>   heaven and earth are joy; And Procla, my wife, believes in the visions
>   that have appeared to her When Li sent the man, she said that I should
>   not That Jesus delivered to the people of Israel, because of their
>   evil intentions When I heard my wife Brockla, that Jesus had risen and
>   appeared in Galilee, I went with Longinus, the Roman commander and
>   twelve soldiers, The same who guarded the tomb, and we went to welcome
>   Christ, As if we would see a great view, and we saw him with his
>   disciples As they stood and marveled, staring at him, He looked at
>   them and said to them, What is this? Do you believe in me? Brockla, as
>   you know it has been said in the covenant that The Lord gave him to
>   the Fathers, that every dead person would live by my death, Which you
>   have seen and you see that I am alive, I have crucified him and I have
>   suffered many things, So I was lying in the grave but now, Hear me and
>   believe in my Father, the God who is in Because I have broken the
>   ropes of death and broken the gates of hell, My coming will be in the
>   future When Brockla and my wife and the Romans heard these things,
>   They came and told me they were pakin, because they were inventing
>   When the evils they did against him and me while I was On the sofa of
>   my bed, I was mourning, I wore a mourning gown, I took fifty Romanian
>   women with my wife and went to Galilee, While I was going on the road
>   I saw these things: That Herod did me these things, that he pointed
>   out, And hindered me to rest my hands against him, and to judge who is
>   trying everyone, And to praise the righteous, Lord of righteousness,
>   and when we approached him, Lord Herod, Heard a great voice from the
>   sky, scary thunder, The earth trembled and a sweet smell rose from it,
>   I never heard of it before, nor did it ever happen In the temple of
>   Jerusalem, while I was standing in the road, The Lord saw me as he
>   stood and spoke with his disciples But I prayed in my heart, because I
>   knew that you gave him to me, He was the Lord of creation and Creator
>   of all, When we saw him, we all fell on our faces In front of his feet
>   and I said loudly, I have sinned, my God, That I have sat down and
>   condemned you, O one who avenge all the truth, and have mercy on me O
>   God of Israel! My wife said with great sadness, O God of heaven and
>   earth, O God of Israel, Do not reward me according to the work of
>   Pontius Pilate, Nor according to the will of the children of Israel,
>   nor according to the thought of the sons of the priests, But remember
>   my husband in your glory! And the Lord drew near, and brought me down
>   My wife and the Romans looked at him and saw him stirring his cross He
>   said, "What all righteous fathers wished to receive, And did not see
>   him, in your days, the Lord of Days, the Son of Man, The Son of the
>   Most High, who forever, rose from death And glorified in the highest
>   of all his creation, and of all What I have established for ever and
>   ever

Comment: Are you asking specificially about the letter you quote or are you asking for other sources of evidence apart from the bible?  If any source, within what time frame from 30 CE?  IOW, there are many that witness to the resurrection apart from the bible within 200 years.

Comment: What evidence is there to suggest that the Arabchurch forum from which you quote has authentic, accurate and verifiable documents?

Comment: @Lesley i don't know ... that's why i asked that question ...  i found these results while searching for "historical evidence about the resurrection of Jesus outside bible"
.....
but maybe this ... it's in other site that have the same Messages .
"These letters link Roman history
And the death of Christ in Jerusalem lies these messages
In a Syriac manuscript in the British Museum,
Dated in the sixth or seventh century there is a copy
Greek Museum in Paris"

Comment: @SLM i don't maybe both ....  "there are many that witness to the resurrection apart from the bible within 200 years" 
but i want  it from verified people like  caiser or herod  . not normal people .

Comment: @Lesley and even i have found these messages all over the internet ... there must be something about it !
[THE REPORT OF PONTIUS PILATE](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/lbob/lbob29.htm#fr_1438)
......
[LETTER OF PILATE TO HEROD.](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/lbob/lbob29.htm#page_270)
.....
[Historic Letter written by Pontius Pilate to Tiberius Caesar About Jesus Life Events – Truth or Fiction?](https://paradisepostblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/17/historic-letter-written-by-pontius-pilate-to-tiberius-caesar-about-jesus-life-events/)

Comment: TBH it seems dubious. Much of the flowery language of conversion and of personal faith seem post-gospel writings, while the letter sounds to be written immediately after the Resurrection in which almost no one, esp Pilate, would have had this type of language in their faith story.  Also, the very broken and almost illiterate nature of the translation shows me that this is not from a translation but someone with poor english trying to write something that sounds like it could be true. If it was from Greek, and translated from Greek, I have confidence it would be translated by a scholar and in

Comment: Cont. A much more scholarly way without the broken english, poor grammatical choice, lack of punctuation, inconsistent concepts, etc. This reeks of someone trying to fabricate evidence. If its real then it would have an accompanying Greek manuscript which would shed a lot more light. Also, Paul was not shy about writing about high profile people to be converted and if the disciples were actually present, someone would have pointed out that Pilate responded to Christ and was converted as it would have been very powerful evidence. The fact that you never hear about him again is telling.

Comment: @Herkfixer thanks mate this seems much reasonable .
although that i found it on a lot of other websites were people shared their opinions about it [like this one](https://www.roger-pearse.com/weblog/2012/05/11/the-letter-of-pilate-to-tiberius/comment-page-1/) but it's little bit different  than our message .